# How to make simplest servlet filter respect setted character encoding

Tags: java, tomcat, groovy, character-encoding

It feels like I'm stuck. 
I'm trying to write the simplest servlet Filter (and deploy it to tomcat). It's a groovy code, but actually I'm heavily using java approaches here, so it is almost copy-paste, that's the reason I've added java tag as well.

My question is - how can I insert UTF-8 string to filter?
Here is the code:

```
public class SimpleFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter

{
    ...
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
           FilterChain chain) 
           throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException
    {   
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()
            chain.doFilter(request, wrapResponse((HttpServletResponse) response))

            response.setCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')
            response.setContentType('text/plain')

            def saw = 'АБВГДЕЙКА ЭТО НЕПРОСТАЯ ПЕРЕДАЧА ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP!!!'
            def bytes = saw.getBytes('UTF-8')
            def content = new String(bytes, 'UTF-8')

            response.setContentLength(content.length())
            out.write(content);
            out.close();
    }   

    private static HttpServletResponse  wrapResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        return new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
            @Override
            public PrintWriter getWriter() {
                 def writer  = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream(), 'UTF-8')
                 return new PrintWriter(writer)
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Content-Type of the filtered page is `text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1`.
So, content type have changed, but charset is ignored.

As you can see, I've take some measures (I guess quite naive) to make sure content is UTF-8, but none of these steps actually was helpful.

I've also tried to add `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` or `useBodyEncodingForUri="true"` attributes to
Connector in tomcat conf/server.xml

It would be nice if somebody explained me what I'm doing wrong.

*UPD:* just a bit of explanation - I'm writing XSLT-applying filter, that is the real reason I'm trying to discard whole request.

Comment: Could you explain us what you want to achieve? If I understand it correctly, this filter calls the rest of the chain, but discards its response. Then it tries to send a hard-coded UTF-8 string to the actual response.

Comment: @JBNizet, actually my intention is to write xslt filter and it turned out to be relatively easy task. The only issue I cannot resolve is correct encoding in response. So, yes, I'm actually discarding response itself, but my intentions are good )))

Comment: That doesn't explain what the filter is supposed to do.

Comment: @JBNizet, while applying filter I'm actually: 1. detecting text/xml content 2. trying to find any stylesheet in response. 3. if found, applying it to the response output 4. replacing response with layout, created with xslt transform. If this approach is inappropriate, feel free to critisize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def saw = 'АБВГДЕЙКА ЭТО НЕПРОСТАЯ ПЕРЕДАЧА ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP!!!'
def bytes = saw.getBytes('UTF-8')
def content = new String(bytes, 'UTF-8')
```

Does not change a thing between saw and content. What you want is to do (using the **outputstream** and **not the writer**, this is why the charset is reset to ISO-8859-1 [See tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29)):

```
out.write(saw.getBytes("UTF-8);
```

Your code looks okay to set the charset as UTF-8.

I don't understand what you are doing with HttpResponseWrapper.

To make it clear, this will work:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
   FilterChain chain) 
   throws java.io.IOException, javax.servlet.ServletException
{   
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()

    response.setCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')
    response.setContentType('text/plain')

    def saw = 'АБВГДЕЙКА ЭТО НЕПРОСТАЯ ПЕРЕДАЧА ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP!!!'

    response.setContentLength(saw.length())
    out.write(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));

}
```

Comment: this is a typo, a silly remnant of my previous approach. As for response.setContentType('text/plain; charset=UTF-8') - I've tried this as well. To understand why I'm trying to do this please, read my answer to @JBNizet. Will edit question to make thing clearer.

Comment: OK, but switch to the outputstream instead of using the writer of the ServletResponse and you will do just fine.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you actually mean, Guillame :(

Comment: I edited my post. You are actually using the PrintWriter of the response which encodes String with encoding ISO-8859-1, this is why your response is always returned with that charset.  Instead use the response outputstream where you can write raw bytes and use whatever encoding you want.

Comment: You mean I should define getOutputStream  in HttpServletResponseWrapper as well? Since just writing this code won't affect on response content at all.

Comment: No just get rid of that wrapper. It is useless.

Comment: Ah-ha-ha, silly me! Thank you very much, Guillame. There are such days when you are stuck and constantly trying to solve the issue which actually even don't need to be solved. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the problem you're having, or at least it's one part of the problem. As the documentation of [`setCharacterEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> This method has no effect if it is called after getWriter has been
>   called or after the response has been committed.

You should set the encoding, **and only after**, get the writer.

Comment: And `setContentLength(bytes.length)`. And `out.flush()` without close.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the content type after committing the response by calling getWriter.
See the documentation on [getWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) and [setCharacterEncoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

To fix you code just move the setting of content type and encoding a few lines earlier.

```
    response.setCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')
    response.setContentType('text/plain')
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()
```

Comment: upvoted yours and JB Nizet answers since I've learned something new from them. Ironically, in this case encoding is setted but Content-Type is for some reason ignored ))) Gillaume pointed out that I should not use HttpServletResponseWrapper at all))