# Return wsdl in a servlet implemented SOAP Web Service

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am implementing a `SOAP` web service in `GAE`. Since `GAE` does not support `JAX-WS` I have chosen to go [this way](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap?hl=es), which is basically building the soap requests and responses myself from a servlet.

Everything works fine but how can I achieve to return the wsdl description in `http://myurl/MyService?wsdl`  ?

I guess I must implement the `GET` method of my servlet but how?

Answer (score 2):

I have enclosed a working implementation. Note that it's based on Servlet 3.0 spec. If you are using 2.5, the annotations wont work.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name="MyWSServlet", urlPatterns={"/MyService"})
public class MyWSServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3605874163075522777L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean requestForWSDL = false;
        Enumeration<String> params = req.getParameterNames();
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            if ("wsdl".equalsIgnoreCase(params.nextElement())) {
                requestForWSDL = true;
            }
        }
        if (requestForWSDL) {
            FileInputStream wsdlInputStream = new FileInputStream(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/wsdl/TemperatureService.wsdl"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            resp.setContentType("application/xml");
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = wsdlInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                resp.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            }
            wsdlInputStream.close();
            resp.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rama, I had it already. I just struggled with the CharacterEncoding and the PrintWriter as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230775/how-to-make-simplest-servlet-filter-respect-setted-character-encoding until I switched to OutputStream like in your example. Thanks